# Kernel crash during Interpolation

Tags: interpolation, crash

I have a kinda large code of a solver, and after somewhat random amount of iterations it causes Kernel to shutdown with a "pop" sound and no messages. I tracked the exact line that caused it, and it was a calculation of Interpolation function on a list of arguments. After I changed the order of interpolation from 10 to 9, the issue disappeared. I saved the data used for interpolation, and there's nothing bad in there. After a kernel starts again there's no issue with interpolation of the last data it was fed with.
Is there any way to trace the error any further?

Comment: A kernel crash of any sort suggests a Mathematica bug.  Are you running out of memory?  Mathematica ought to catch that, but these things are hard.  If you are, you might find a way of reducing your memory usage.  Otherwise, I guess that you are out of luck.  You might report a bug, but that's unlikely to solve your immediate problem.

Comment: @mikado less than 1GB, plenty of memory available. I guess 9th order it is then.

Comment: These non-reproducible crash-type bugs are the most annoying and one wonders what Wolfram does with their reports. Presumably if they get enough of them they will look into it, otherwise I expect they just file them. I have a long collection of such that I have never bothered reporting.